# Can Background Worker Processes access data directly using shared-memory in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

The current [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bgworker.html) seems (to me) to imply that you need to use a DB connection to read/write data in PostgreSQL, just like a "normal client", but some articles on the web seem to imply that you can implement some form of "replication" using *shared-memory* in Background Worker Processes, with a recent versions of PostgreSQL. I might have understood that incorrectly.

So, can Background Worker Processes access (read/write) data directly using *shared-memory* in PostgreSQL?

The purpose of the question is to know if (measurable) performance benefits could be achieved using this, presumably complicated and dangerous, method of access. In an ideal world, I would have wanted to use PostgreSQL as a single-process "embedded" DB, but PG cannot do that. It seems like "Background Worker Processes" + "shared-memory" is the closest I can get to that.

Reasons to not use *SQLite*, if I want an embedded DB, is lack of support of arrays, and composite types, like in PG. *Firebird* would be an alternative, but also lack composite types.

Comment: Is it possible you can get better performance with a better data model/queries/etc, or have you ruled that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong track.

A background worker can access shared buffers and other shared memory structures as well as the database files, but doing so directly and breaking the abstraction rules inside the server will lead to chaos and destruction rather than improved performance.

If you want to run an SQL statement in a background worker process or any other server process, you request a connection with `BackgroundWorkerInitializeConnection`. This is not a normal client connection, it allows you to execute SQL statements via the [SPI interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html).

I don't see how all that gets you closer to using PostgreSQL like an embedded database. Communicating with a background worker from another process is no better (and probably much more complicated) than establishing a normal client-server connection via UNIX sockets. Why write your own background process if a regular session backend process already can do the same for you?

If you want an embedded database, use something like SQLite.

Comment: +1 As mentionned in the original question, SQLite is unforunately out of question, because of lack of support of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

A background worker can use a built in connection by the [server programming interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html).
See the example in src/test/modules/worker_spi/worker_spi.c.  You could use this to run queries without the overhead of interprocess communication, other than that needed for locking.

It can also access shared memory directly without going through the SPI, but it is hard to see what the use of that would be for your case.

Comment: +1 I like that you answered my question very clearly and directly: "You could use this to run queries without the overhead of interprocess communication", but I'm choosing @LaurenzAlbe answer, because he went in more details, and also answered first.